# Why doesn't manual focus work with my Nikon D7200 and AF-S 300mm f/4 ED?

Tags: nikon, manual-focus, af-s

I have finally gotten myself a D7200 (2.017 & 1.04 firmware) and a 300mm f4/D AF-S (non VR version). My lens's serial number is 33xxxx.

AF works, but manual focus does not work.
I have tried settings M/AF (body) and M/A or M (lens), but still nothing happens. When I switch the lens to MF, I can turn the focus ring, but the metering/indicator on lens is still silent.

Could there be something wrong with the camera or the lens?

Comment: See [How do I diagnose the source of focus problem in a camera?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/87861/75526)

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by silent? The 'beep' that can sometimes be associated with autofocus if one likes (or does not turn off the default), is not the only way one knows the image is sharp. And I'd be surprised if it was associated with manual focus. With most Nikons, in the lower left of the viewfinder, there is a little ball which shows up when the focus point selected, is in focus. Otherwise, a arrow on the left or right will show up, indicating which direction you need to go. Do the images come out sharp when you use manual focus, snap a shot, and enlarge the focus area?

Comment: Does focus *change* when you turn the focus ring? It sounds like you are looking for an electronic indicator, but let's check the basics first.

Comment: You should see the focus visually change when looking through the view finder. When using the focus indicator, you need to take the camera out of standby mode by half pressing the shutter release. The focus indicator will only work when the camera is in active mode. See page 10, item 11 in your manual.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the [Manual](https://cdn-10.nikon-cdn.com/pdf/manuals/lenses/AF/AF-S_300mm_f4.pdf) of the lens the autofocus should be active in M/A mode on the lens but you should have the possibility to make always adjustments with the focus ring. There should always be the possibility to do this and to change the focus also if the autofocus is turned on. 
If it is not working in your case you should consider to take it to a professional and let it check (many Nikon stores with NPS will do this for you for an ok prize for Nikon lenses).

The camera should not be the problem for this because the AF switch on the D7200 only activates/deactivates the sensor port so no AF data is send to the Lens and turns on and off the motor in the camera if the lens has no AF system.