# Picture gets blurry when zooming in

Tags: nikon, focus, sharpness, kit-lens, nikon-d3400

My Nikon 3400's kit lens(18-55mm) works fine when I take pictures at 18mm. But when I extend lens beyond that, the picture gets blurry(no clarity). Though I can focus on extremely close distances while using anything beyond 18mm, but cant take any landscape shots while zooming.
I have tried switching from auto to manual focus.
Tried to take pictures in proper light too.
P.s: It all started after I tried to shoot in extremely low light condition.

Comment: Try a different lens on the same camera, or try the suspect lens on a different camera, or both, to resolve whether it's a lens or camera issue.

Comment: Related: [How do I diagnose the source of focus problem in a camera?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/87861/15871) The accepted answer also cover many possible causes, other than focus related problems, that can make pictures blurry.

Comment: What exposure times (shutter "speeds") are you using?

Comment: What is the exact name of the lens?

Answer (score 1):

> I can focus on extremely close

The closest focus a Nikon 18-55 should work at is about 25cm - that's about 10 inches.

If you can focus much closer than that it is a fault.  It likely needs to be repaired or replaced.

Before going down that route try a factory reset on the off chance it is an odd computer issue (which seems unlikely, but these gadgets are quite complex computers now).

> My Nikon 3400's kit lens(18-55mm) works fine when I take pictures at 18mm. But when I extend lens beyond that, the picture gets blurry(no clarity)

Again this suggests (to me) a physical fault with the lens.

> It all started after I tried to shoot in extremely low light condition.

I cannot see how that would cause a problem.  It could be a coincidence and the fault would have developed anyway.