# Nikon D5300 pictures are coming out blurry

Tags: focus

When I'm taking pictures in Autofocus on my Nikon d5300 the subject's face comes out blurry. It's not the camera shaking, the shutter speed was on 1/200. It didn't help to zoom in, however, when I zoomed in on half a bench with a little bit of the background it was very clear. It works perfectly fine in Manual focus, Just not in auto. I've noticed it happen before but then it goes away until it comes back. Before I take the picture it looks fine and the right parts are in focus but not in the actual picture, the whole thing is blurry though in some the backround is perfectly clear. I tried locking the focus when I got it to focus on the face but that didn't help. Anyone know whats wrong with it?

Comment: Without seeing some examples it's hard to tell. Since you don't have enough reputation yet to post photos to a question, can you provide links in a comment so that one of use can edit the examples into your question? You can use something like imgur or flickr to host the images. As it stands now, your question will likely be closed due to lack of details.

Comment: Here's our generic, everything but the kitchen sink, question regarding issues that can result in blurry subjects: [How do I diagnose the source of focus problem in a camera?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/87861/15871)

Comment: Details like which lens you used is helpful. 1/200sec with a tele might be not a clear case that the focus was not good. So the more info you can provide, the better the answers might get.